# jQuery if else unordered list addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` with four `li` elements. I want to check to see which one has the class `.selected`. If the `li` hasClass `.selected`, do nothing. If another `.li` in the same list does NOT have the `.selected` class, I want to add the class `.li-border`. In the code example below, I can get the console.log to fire but not the addClass. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
if ($("ul.portfolio-nav li a").hasClass("selected")) {
    console.log("yo");
} else {
    $(this).addClass("li-border");
};
```

Comment: This is checking if a has the selected class.

Comment: To what refers `this`? Show us the HTML and the event handler leading to this function call

Comment: Also it seems the element holding the `.selected` is an <a> element not the <ul>, can you confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code :

```js
$("ul.portfolio-nav li a").each(function(){
    if ( !$(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
        $(this).addClass("li-border");
    };
});
```

```css
.li-border{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='portfolio-nav'>
    <li><a href='#'>First element</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class="selected">Second and selected element</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Third element</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did it! I was thinking that the .each function would work but I wasn't sure how to implement it. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @BR You must consider an answer below by GolezTrol which makes it with just one line of code.

Comment: @MarkSkayff you have to respect his choice, maybe he want to add extra instructions not just assigning a class, so that will be the best choice for him, anyway thanks for your comment, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The `:not` selector should do the trick:

```
$("ul.portfolio-nav li a:not(.selected)").addClass('li-border');
```

Or alternatively use the '.not' function, [as suggested by jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("ul.portfolio-nav li a").not(".selected").addClass('li-border');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't over complicate yourself. Just remove all li-border class then add it to the one set you want to match too.

https://jsfiddle.net/da98dmgt/7/

```
$("ul.portfolio-nav li").click(function(){
    $("ul.portfolio-nav  ul li").removeClass("li-border");
    $(this).siblings("li").addClass("li-border");
});
```

Comment: Well, at least it makes you understand the use of .each. Looks like it was the selected answer though. My preferred was the one below.

Comment: I'll give you that. My solution still stands as valid though - My experience has been that it is best to try and avoid complicating javascript code for individual pages like this probably is. For debugging's sake later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. It should be easy to replace the styles with the one you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list-items li").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).addClass('disable');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li:hover,
.selected {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}
.disable {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list-items">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li class="selected">Selected item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```